# How to run a SQL command to update some opencart products to non taxable items?

Tags: sql, opencart

I currently have about 4000 products in my Opencart 1.5.5.1 store, Currently ALL products are set to "taxable" items. I have about 500 of these products that are in fact "none taxable" products.

I would like to be able to run a SQL command to update the 500 products using phpmyadmin to change the 500 products. I need to have set as NONE under the tax class in the products.

Does anyone know how to complete such a task using a SQL commend?

Here is part of the products DB file. This one is of two products I manually changed in opencarts admin area on two products - I made the tax class as NONE:

```
INSERT INTO `oc_product` (`product_id`, `model`, `sku`, `upc`, `ean`, `jan`, `isbn`, `mpn`, `location`, `quantity`, `stock_status_id`, `image`, `manufacturer_id`, `shipping`, `price`, `points`, `tax_class_id`, `date_available`, `weight`, `weight_class_id`, `length`, `width`, `height`, `length_class_id`, `subtract`, `minimum`, `sort_order`, `status`, `date_added`, `date_modified`, `viewed`, `call_for_price`, `custom_message`, `youtubevideo`) VALUES
(1, 'AAJ - 101', 'AAJ - 101', 'AAJ - 101', '', '', '', '', '', 0, 5, 'data/Products/Americolor/Americolor-Black-Soft-Gel-Paste-.75oz.jpg', 1, 1, '0.0000', 0, 0, '2013-01-09', '0.00000000', 1, '0.00000000', '0.00000000', '0.00000000', 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, '2013-01-09 22:25:59', '2013-05-13 02:01:06', 10, 0, '', ''),
(2, 'AAJ - 102', 'AAJ - 102', 'AAJ - 102', '', '', '', '', '', 0, 5, 'data/Products/Americolor/Americolor-Royal-Blue-soft-gel-paste-0.75oz.jpg', 1, 1, '0.0000', 0, 0, '2013-01-09', '0.00000000', 1, '0.00000000', '0.00000000', '0.00000000', 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, '2013-01-09 22:25:59', '2013-05-13 02:01:06', 4, 0, '', ''),
```

This is 2 of them that the Tax is assigned to:

```
(11, 'AAJ - 111', 'AAJ - 111', 'AAJ - 111', '', '', '', '', '', 0, 5, 'data/Products/Americolor/Americolor-Leaf-Green-Soft-Gel-Paste-.75oz.jpg', 1, 1, '0.0000', 0, 9, '2013-01-09', '0.00000000', 1, '0.00000000', '0.00000000', '0.00000000', 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, '2013-01-09 22:25:59', '2013-05-13 02:01:06', 6, 0, '', NULL),
(12, 'AAJ - 112', 'AAJ - 112', 'AAJ - 112', '', '', '', '', '', 0, 5, 'data/Products/Americolor/Americolor-Mint-Green-Soft-Gel-Paste-.75oz.jpg', 1, 1, '0.0000', 0, 9, '2013-01-09', '0.00000000', 1, '0.00000000', '0.00000000', '0.00000000', 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, '2013-01-09 22:25:59', '2013-05-13 02:01:06', 6, 0, '', NULL)
```

Comment: Show the table and show the code you have ..

Comment: Sorry? What exactly do you want to see? The products table has about 4000 products in it. I am not sure what you want me to actually add here. I dont have any code to show as this is why I am asking how to do this.

Comment: I mean part of them .. maybe 4 or 6 (just for example) .. I'm sure there's someone can help you in this ..

Comment: I have added 2 examples, the first is of the 2 products I manually changed to NONE (for non tax) inthe OC admin area. The second is of 2 products that are set as Taxable. I have noticed the number 9 in the second one, that I assume would represent the taxable item, while the first one has a zero in the spot where I assume the 9 would have been... But to change 500 products, I simply dont know, so hopefully someone may have a really helpful answer. I have made query changes before by following instructions successfully, so I dont mind learning a new curve :) Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If You do not know the rule or at least the IDs of these products, then You cannot achieve this by SQL query.

If You have those IDs, though, You could execute this SQL query:

```sql
UPDATE product SET tax_class_id = 0 WHERE product_id IN (<COMA_SEPARATED_PRODUCT_IDS_TO_BE_UPDATED>);
```

If You know some other rule that applies, You could then do:

```sql
UPDATE product SET tax_class_id = 0 WHERE <YOUR_RULE(S)_COMES_HERE>;
```

Nothing more could be advised...

Comment: Ok, Thanks, I will give this a go. This can apply to SKU number as well? Instead of product_id I could add sku and then add the sku numbers seperated by commas? Do I have this right?

Comment: Exactly, You could use other columns to restrict the products to be updated. But when using `VARCHAR` columns do not forget to put the values in apostrophes `'`, so it would be `WHERE sku IN ('SKU1', 'SKU12', 'SKU265')`.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much for all your help it worked perfectly, I am so happy now... Thanks again.